# Better way to Schedule Alarms on Flutter Apps?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, alarmmanager

As of now for my **alarm** app, I used the Flutter local notification plugin to schedule notification and play the alarm ringtone by keeping the alarm ringtone as the notification sound in the code.
But because of this, in some Android and iOS devices, the sound is not playing. Is there any way better way to schedule alarms in Flutter?

Here is the code for notification that I did:

```
class SetAlarm {
  static Future<void> setAlarmtoStorage({
    int id,
    TimeOfDay alarmTime,
  }) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pref.setStringList('$id', [alarmTime.hour.toString(), alarmTime.minute.toString()]);
  }

  static Future<TimeOfDay> getAlarmfromStorage({int id}) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final hourAndMin = pref.getStringList('$id');
    final time = TimeOfDay(
      hour: int.parse(hourAndMin[0]),
      minute: int.parse(hourAndMin[1]),
    );
    return time;
  }

  static Future<void> cancelAlarm(int id) async {
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(id);
  }

  static Future<void> setAlarm(TimeOfDay selectedTime, int id) async {
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    final String currentTimeZone = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
    print(currentTimeZone);
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(currentTimeZone));
    var notifydate;
    final hour = (TimeOfDay.now().hour - selectedTime.hour).abs();
    final min = (TimeOfDay.now().minute - selectedTime.minute).abs();
    if (tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).isAfter(DateTime(
      DateTime.now().year,
      DateTime.now().month,
      DateTime.now().day,
      selectedTime.hour,
      selectedTime.minute,
    ))) {
      notifydate = tz.TZDateTime.local(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
          DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1)).day, selectedTime.hour, selectedTime.minute);
      // tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local)
      //     .subtract(Duration(seconds: tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).second))
      //     .add(Duration(days: 1, hours: hour, minutes: min));
      print(notifydate.toString());
      print('isAfter true(alarm time is after the now date)');
    } else {
      notifydate = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local)
          .subtract(Duration(seconds: tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).second))
          .add(Duration(hours: hour, minutes: min));
      print('isAfter:false');
    }
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'alarm_notify',
      'alarm_notify',
      'Channel for Alarm notification',
      icon: 'time',
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('alarm_ringtone'),
      largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('time'),
      playSound: true,
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails(
      sound: 'alarm_ringtone.mp3',
      presentAlert: true,
      presentBadge: true,
      presentSound: true,
    );
    var platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      'Alarm',
      'Wake Up!!!',
      notifydate,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }
}
```

I did all the setup required for flutter local notification. I even kept the sound in the raw folder inside res.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: I have added now @VinayHP